# driver for Canon scanner 8400F

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner

I am looking for driver CanoScan series 8000 more specific 8400F.
Can a driver for OSx be used in Ubuntu.
The scanner is in the USB list but can not be used. Scanning programs gives the message no scanner found.

Answer (score 1):

The OSx driver can't work. You need a Linux driver. If the scanner is connected properly, the kernel will identify it together with other USB devices:

*lsusb*

If it does, but XSane doesn't, check on the Sane Project website (http://www.sane-project.org) if your scanner is listed as supported.

If it's not, you need to look for the driver on the Canon website. Consider yourself lucky if you find one. Canon is worse than ANY other major vendor when it comes to Linux driver support.

Comment: Sane does not have a driver for the 8400F